# Read source code by view-source with the help of JS or jQuery or any client scripting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to read the source code of a url like `view-source:http://example.com`. I don't want to use Ajax to read the source like `http://example.com`.

Only want to read source with `view-source:http://`

Does anybody have any idea how can i achieve my goal.

Comment: I believe it's not possible since `view-source` is a browser feature, and not some part of http protocol. Why don't you want to read the source via Ajax?

Comment: No I can't use ajax for this. Does web page response stored in temp files??

Comment: Oh, I see. You want to read the source of a page that was loaded before and might be stored in cache? And you want to do it whith JS from another page?

Comment: yes exactly i want this only first my page will load in browser after this i want to read source of that page with out hitting another request of that page.

Comment: Try : [Make a view source button](https://css-tricks.com/make-a-view-source-button/)

Answer (score 0):

You definetely could not access an arbitrary file from user's filesystem, as that would be a severe security breach.

However, You might look at [Service Workers](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/service-worker/introduction/?redirect_from_locale=ru).

Amongst other things, Service Workers allow you to cache specific pages, and open these pages later without network connection. (They call it "offline-first apps".)

This is a new spec, so it is supported only by latest versions of Chrome, Firefox and Opera. Anyway, I believe that's your best choice for now.

**Update.** Here is a [thorough article](https://dbwriteups.wordpress.com/2015/11/16/service-workers-part-2-offline-caching-patterns/) specifically on Service Workers caching patterns.

Comment: Yes. It's production-ready tech, though you should be careful with older browsers.

Comment: You might like to check out a [demo](https://bastsoft.github.io/tomato/) of a collegue of mine. Source is on [github](https://github.com/bastsoft/tomato). You could load the site once, the turn off the network connection and refresh the page.